# Is it possible to make light pass through only a part of the texture

Tags: light, transparency

I have a light inside an object, and that object has a material with transparent parts.

I want to render light beams radiating from those parts with volume scatter, however, the light doesn't pass beyond the mesh.

Is there a way to let light pass through those transparent parts of the texture?

[image]

[image: render]
[image: nodes]

Comment: Can you post your current nodes?

Comment: I posted it in the main post because Im a noob and cant add images lol. I also tried using light path node but thats not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a mix shader connected to a transparency and diffuse nodes, the texture is the one that controls the mix:

[image]

Then just use volume scattering in the world volume.

Usually the default density for volume scatter is way to high, so play with the values until you find the right one for your needs.

keep in mind also that the emitter object inside might need to be quite bright.

[image]

Comment: I swear I have the same setup, even when I disable shadows for the object, volume scatter works, but otherwise, the light doesnt pass beyond the mesh at all..  I will try to play with it a bit, but thank you for your answer, as I see, it should totaly work

Comment: @Jared I uploaded the file for you as part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it in a new project with my object and your setup and it works. I must have changed something accidentally in the old one or I dont know.